# CKAN fail to create sysadmin

Tags: postgresql, ckan

I managed to install ckan by follwing this steps [Here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html)

Everything is working fine until here `ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini db init` I also get this message `Initialising DB: SUCCESS` suggesting that everything is fine.

But now when I run `ckan -c /etc/ckan/default/ckan.ini sysadmin add admin email=admin@ckanadmin.com name=admin`

I got this

> [SQL: INSERT INTO activity (id, timestamp, user_id, object_id, revision_id, activity_type, data, permission_labels) VALUES (%(id)s, %(timestamp)s, %(user_id)s, %(object_id)s, %(revision_id)s, %(activity_type)s, %(data)s, %(permission_labels)s)]
> [parameters: {'id': '64314f70-053e-4eb6-b6bd-30ae71088a47', 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 17, 7, 52, 19, 215902), 'user_id': 'd84ec396-2be7-40fd-858a-6d215fb9133e', 'object_id': 'd84ec396-2be7-40fd-858a-6d215fb9133e', 'revision_id': None, 'activity_type': 'new user', 'data': None, 'permission_labels': None}]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

Can anyone help me please?

I search everywhere online but I can't find any help

Comment: 1) I don't actually see an error message I just see the query and it's parameters. Can you provide the part where it calls out the error? 2) If not look at the Postgres log and see what it says. 3) Best bet is the user you are running the command as does not have the necessary privileges  to make a user as sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver, i finally managed to solve the issue. the problem was i installed ckan 2.11.0a0 which is not stable yet, then I have to remove it and install ckan 2.10 and the issue was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue. the problem was i installed ckan 2.11.0a0 which is not stable yet, then I have to remove it and install ckan 2.10 and the issue was solved